# MAUI AppShell route works on Android but not on Windows

Tags: maui, app-shell

I made a demo maui app and I have found that this line of code:

```
AppShell.Current.GoToAsync("//HomeMenu");
```

works fine when the app is run to an Android local device but does not work when the app is running as a Windows app.

I have registered the routes in AppShell.cs like this:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(HomeMenu), typeof(HomeMenu));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(But2Page), typeof(But2Page));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(But2Sub), typeof(But2Sub));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(But2SubSub), typeof(But2SubSub));
```

Here is a representation of the ContentPages I am displaying for this use case:

```
Home Menu
    - Button2 Page
        □ Button 2 Sub Page
            - Button 2 Sub Sub Page
```

Here are the commands that the code executes to walk down that hierarchy

```
AppShell.Current.GoToAsync("But2Page");
AppShell.Current.GoToAsync("But2Sub");
AppShell.Current.GoToAsync("But2SubSub");
```

That all works fine on both platforms.  On the But2SubSub page the code does the following:

```
AppShell.Current.GoToAsync("//HomeMenu");
```

On Android the app displays the Home Menu page.  On Windows the  value at the top of the page displays "Home Menu" but the page content remains the But2SubSub content:

[image]

NOTE:  I have not declared any routes at all in the AppShell.xaml file.  It simply has this:

```
<ShellContent
    Title="HomeMenu"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomeMenu}"
    Route="HomeMenu" />
```

How can I make the last GoToAsync method work correctly in the Windows app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same route defined twice. You have

```xml
<ShellContent
     Title="HomeMenu"
     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomeMenu}"
     Route="HomeMenu" />
```

And also

```cs
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(HomeMenu), typeof(HomeMenu));
```

So I suggest you remove the RegisterRoute and it will work.

Comment: I removed the RegisterRoute and I still get the same results.  It works on the Android device and not in the Windows version of the app.  I deleted the bin and obj directories for good measure.  Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, it is still valid so keep it. Try this: `Routing.RegisterRoute(HomeMenu/But2Sub, typeof(But2Sub));` and then `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//HomeMenu/But2Sub");`

Comment: I agree with Peter's comment. What you did "should" have worked, but I suspect a bug was introduced when trying to fix a different navigation bug. This workaround, telling Shell that `But2Sub` is "under" `HomeMenu`, should correctly remove `But2Sub` from the nav stack, when navigating back to `//HomeMenu`. If this doesn't fix it, please make a public github repo with just enough info to reproduce the problem, and create a new issue at `github maui issues`. (Even if it does fix it, you are welcome to make a new issue and repo; I think it is genuinely a bug.)

Comment: @PeterWessberg your suggestion did not work. There are missing quotes and when the code executes the But2Sub page displays,  Which makes sense b c the RegisteredRoute has typeof(But2Sub).  I want the HomeMenu page to display.   See what you think of the solution I came up with below.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, the app is displaying the But2SubSub page and I want the code (a button click) to make the app display the HomeMenu page.  The following edits work.

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("SomeUniqueName", typeof(HomeMenu));
```

Then in the click handler:

```
AppShell.Current.GoToAsync("SomeUniqueName");
```

I have a lot of navigation on a lot of button clicks in the app, because that is what I am testing out, and that all still works with the changes above.